# Create a LINQ query that fetches data from two Entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, wcf

I want to get to the product categories in a MVC project and use them to create a menu. The model resides on a WCF project  so I have instantiated it as follows:

```
ServiceReference1.WSClient client = new ServiceReference1.WSClient();
```

My Product model is like this:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public string ProductImagePath { get; set; }

    public string Specifications { get; set; }

    public string Options { get; set; }

    public double? UnitPrice { get; set; }

    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }

    public  Category Category { get; set; }

    public int Stock { get; set; }
}
```

My Category model is like this:

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public string Despcription { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

}
```

I want to get the product categories like this:

```
public PartialViewResult Menu()
{

    List<Product> products = client.GetAvailableProducts().ToList();


    IEnumerable<string> categories = products
                                 .Select(myproduct => myproduct.Category.CategoryName) // <- offending line
                                 .Distinct()
                                 .OrderBy(x => x);

    return PartialView(categories);
}
```

The method GetAvailableProducts() works because I get a list of products so I know that the service is working. However, when run the application, I get a null reference exception at the Linq query(see offending line above).

It seems to me that categories has to be instantiated but then, how to construct the LINQ query so that the Category is also instantiated? Can anyone point out how to do it?

BR,

Gabriel

Answer (score 3):

When you serialize the *Products* in the service you should use [LoadWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.loadwith%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to also serialize any linked entities. This is because the default is *lazy loading* and EF won't load the linked entities until accessed. When you serialize the *Products*, *Category* is not accessed. `LoadWith` will perform an *eager load* so that all data will be serialized.

Example:

```
public IEnumerable<Product> GetAvailableProducts()
{
  var ctx = new ProductsContext();

  DataLoadOptions dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
  dlo.LoadWith<Product>(p => p.Category);
  ctx.LoadOptions = dlo;

  return ctx.Products.ToList();
}
```

**Edit:**

Guess it's too late in the afternoon. :(

`LoadWith` is used in conjuction with `Linq to SQL`.
With `Entity Framework` you should use [Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead:

```
public IEnumerable<Product> GetAvailableProducts()
{
  var ctx = new ProductsContext();
  return ctx.Products.Include("Category").ToList();
}
```

**Disclaimer:** *Code not tested*

Comment: I am trying this approach but I think I need an assembly reference which one would it be?

Comment: From the documentation: `System.Data.Linq`

Comment: Oh Thank you, I see now, I was using System.Linq; but I could not get it... I am testing now ;-)

Comment: when I do this I get an error: error occurred while receiving the HTTP response.

Comment: Thank you! It worked  when removing the collection of products from the Category entity I am not sure why but it does not work when marked virtual. I also noticed that in the return statement whichyou wrote the parenthesis after products is not necessary.

Comment: If you have `Product` in `Category` it will create a circular reference serialization. Removing Product from Category is one way of solving the problem. But that is not always acceptable. Another way of solving this is to use DTOs', Data Transfer Objects. So instead of serializing `IEnumerable<Product>` you serialize `IEnumerable<ProductDTO>` which contains a reference to `CategoryDTO` which doesn't contain a reference back to `Product` or `ProductDTO`. In this way you can still maintain your datamodel and now you've also decoupled the datamodel from the viewmodel/clientmodel.

Answer (score 2):

You're pulling down the Products successfully but your service is not pulling down the related categories.

Thus, when you do `myproduct.Category.CategoryName`, `Category` is always `null`.

You need to tell the service to return the related categories.

Comment: I guess this is achieved with Sani's approach above... Is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your relationship is a 0 or 1 to many since CategoryId is an int?.  If the Category is null, then you can't do Category.CategoryName.  That's a null reference.

Answer (score 1):

On your offending line, myproduct.Category, there is one or more null Category. You need to change

```
client.GetAvailableProducts().ToList();
```

to also pull down the Category that each product is composed of.

You should also guard for the inevitable null Category.